# Change Date Format in Trello.NET

Tags: serialization, date-format, restsharp, trello

I have used [Trello.NET](https://github.com/dillenmeister/trellonet) to integrate Trello into our own bugtracking application.

Our own application has an european date format (dd/MM/yyyy). the Trello API has an American format (MM/dd/yyyy). TrelloNet uses RestSharp to do the REST communication.

How can change the serialization output to MM/dd/yyyy?

Kind Regard,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Trello.NET which was fixed in version 0.5.2.